# Read file parquet file from s3 in java

Tags: java, amazon-s3, parquet

I am new to Java & spark sql. I wanted to know if there is a way to read a file of type Spark Parquet format saved as JSON in S3 in my Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[1]")
      .getOrCreate()

spark.read().json("s3a://your/json/path.json")

spark.write().parquet("parquet/file/path.parquet")
```

Comment: Thank you for the approach. I have followed this approach, but I get the below error 

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found` 

I have created a sparkSession like this:

`SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("AppName")
                .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
.master("local[1]")
              .getOrCreate()`

Could you please let me know what am I missing?

Comment: do not use `NativeS3FileSystem` jsue default S3 implementation and access s3 files from spark with `s3a://`